# HAProxy cuts parameters in log

Tags: haproxy

Good day everyone!

I’m migrated from haproxy 1.5 to 1.7.11 and I have some troubles with logging

I have a following in config file for logging

```
 capture request  header Host len 200
 capture request  header Referer len 200
 capture request  header User-Agent len 200
 capture request  header Content-Type len 200
 capture request  header Cookie len 300
 log-format %[capture.req.hdr(0),lower]\ %ci\ -\ [%t]\ \"%HM\ %HP\ %HV\"\ %ST\ \"%[capture.req.hdr(3)]\"\ %U\ \"%[capture.req.hdr(1)]\"\ \"%[capture.req.hdr(2)]\"\ \"%[capture.req.hdr(4)]\"\ %Tq\ \"%s\"\ 'NGINX-CACHE-- "-"'\ \"%ts\»
```

Logformat is almost the same with Nginx

But is some cases it works incorrectly

For example log output

```
Nov 20 10:41:56 lb.loc haproxy[12633]: example.com 81.4.227.173 - [20/Nov/2019:10:41:56.095] "GET /piwik.php H" 200 "-" 2396 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0" "some.cookie data" 19 "vm06.lb.loc" NGINX-CACHE-- "-" "—"
```

Problem is that "GET /piwik.php H"  must be "GET /piwik.php HTTP/1.1" 
its %HV parameter in log-format

A part of "HTTP/1.1" randomly cut’s off. It may be "HT" or "HTT" or "HTTP/1."

Answer (score 0):

I think we have discussed this on the HAProxy mailing list.
https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg35426.html

There are some bug fixes in the buffer handling therefore please try to update to the latest 1.7.

As you mentioned on the HAProxy list that you use CentOS 6 and you use the packages from ius repo please install 1.7.12 which is listed on the page below.

https://repo.ius.io/6/x86_64/packages/h/

Answer (score 0):

As described in documentation:

> req.hdr(): [...] The function considers any comma as a delimiter for distinct values. If full-line headers are desired instead, use req.fhdr(). [...]

So, you should use `req.fhdr()` to have the full header value.

For example, like this:

`http-request capture req.fhdr(User-Agent) len 256k`

*Information from [issue](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/353) thread in official repository.*